# Saving data to the join table using control options in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, join

I learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905543/saving-additional-data-to-the-join-table-in-the-add-method-in-cakephp-3-0) how one can save the data to the fields of join table `CoursesMemberships` while adding or editing a `student` in CakePHP 3.x. In order to add `grades` for many `courses` I can do this in my `add` and `edit` forms:

```
echo $this->Form->control('courses.0.id', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $courses]);
echo $this->Form->control('courses.0._joinData.grade');

echo $this->Form->control('courses.1.id', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $courses]);
echo $this->Form->control('courses.1._joinData.grade');

echo $this->Form->control('courses.2.id', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $courses]);
echo $this->Form->control('courses.2._joinData.grade');
...
```

but this form:

1. has a fixed number of `courses` for each `student`;
2. requires to select the `course id` from the list (`'type' => 'select'`);
3. adds all courses to the student record even if not attended (well, the corresponding `grade` field can be kept empty, but still).

Is there a way to have a simpler form, where all `courses` are listed and one can only checkbox the `course` attended and enter the corresponding `grade`? I found it very challenging using `control`...

**EDIT:**
After `@ndm` suggested a very nice method below, I implemented it in the `add.ctp`:

```
foreach ($courses as $key => $course) {

echo $this->Form->control('courses.'.$key.'.id', ['type' => 'checkbox', 'hiddenField' => false, 'value' => $key,
    'label' => $key]);
echo $this->Form->control('courses.'.$key.'._joinData.grades');
}
```

and corrected `StudentsTable.php` accordingly. And it runs with no problems.

However, if I do the same in `edit.ctp`, the previously saved records (e.g. for 1, 3, 5 and 7 `courses` are now listed as 1, 2 and 3 showing the `grades` for former 3rd 5th and 7th `courses` and the form forces me to check those three boxes. I understand that the first record disappeared because my `courses` start with `id=1` (and so does the $key in the loop) and 'courses.0.id' is thus missing, but the general problem is that the empty fields removed by `beforeMarshal` function are no longer recognized in `edit.ctp` form and I cannot find a reasonable way to edit the `student's` record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build in support for what you are trying to achieve, you'll have to come up with a custom solution, which will likely either require a mixture of form and marshalling logic, or JavaScript.

You could create for example a list of checkboxes, and use the `id` value (wich will be zero in case the checkbox isn't checked, or the ID in case it *is* checked) to remove unchecked entries from the submitted data before marshalling, something like this:

```
echo $this->Form->control('courses.0.id', [
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'value' => $courses[0]->id,
    'label' => $courses[0]->title
]);
echo $this->Form->control('courses.0._joinData.grade');

echo $this->Form->control('courses.1.id', [
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'value' => $courses[1]->id,
    'label' => $courses[1]->title
]);
echo $this->Form->control('courses.1._joinData.grade');

// ...
```

```
// in the `StudentsTable` class

public function beforeMarshal(\Cake\Event\Event $event, \ArrayObject $data, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    forach ($data['courses'] as $key => $course) {
        if (empty($course['id'])) {
            unset($data['courses'][$key])
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use JavaScript to disable the controls related to the checkbox so that they aren't being submitted in the first place. For this to work properly you'll need to make sure that you disable the hidden field that is by default being generated for checkboxes (see the `hiddenField` option), as otherwise zero will be sent for unchecked checkboxes.

Here's a quick, untested jQuery example to illustrate the principle:

```php
echo $this->Form->control('courses.0.id', [
    'class' => 'course-checkbox',
    'data-join-data-input' => '#course-join-data-0',
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'hiddenField' => false, // no fallback, unchecked boxes aren't being submitted
    'value' => $courses[0]->id,
    'label' => $courses[0]->title
]);
echo $this->Form->control('courses.0._joinData.grade', [
    'id' => 'course-join-data-0',
    'disabled' => true
]);

// ...
```

```
$('.course-checkbox').each(function () {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    var $joinDataInput = $($checkbox.data('join-data-input'));

    $checkbox.on('change', function () {
        $joinDataInput.prop('disabled', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Modifying Request Data Before Building Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#modifying-request-data-before-building-entities)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Select, Checkbox and Radio Controls > Options for Control](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-control)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Select, Checkbox and Radio Controls > Creating Checkboxes](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-checkboxes)**

Comment: I am very grateful to you for the elegant solutions and detailed explanation! I started to implement the first one and got this error message: Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\Query as array  (line 'value' => $courses[0]->id,)

Comment: You'd have to convert it to an array first using `$courses->toArray()`, and `$courses` would need to be a regular query (not a list one). I assumed that you want to generated a specific number of courses given your example snippet. Alternatively you could iterate over `$courses`, and use key/value instead of accessing properties in case `$courses` is a list finder query.

Comment: Amazing! Everything works as you explained. As always. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited the main question to make it clear that one of the solutions works perfectly for add method, but, at least in my implementation, does not provide the way to edit.

Comment: I am implementing the resetpassword functionality and the beforeMarshal function above is now making troubles because it becomes active when I try to update the user's password. Is there any way to escape it?

Comment: @VincentVega I don't know what that functionality looks like, and I have no clue how removing empty courses may affect it, but surely there should be a way. That's something for a new question.